# field name entered are still inserted in database. (PHP)

Tags: php, validation

I have this validation code:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

$tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
{

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $add=$_POST['add'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];

   if(($name!="")&&($lname!="")&&($add!="")&&($age!="")&&($contact!="")&& ($email!="")&&($user!="")&&($pass!=""))
   {
      if ($_POST['user']==$row['username'])
      {
            header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");

      }

      else
      {
      $value=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(name, lastname, address, age, contact,email, username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['add']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['pass']."')");
  }
   }
   else 
   {
 header("location: /register.php?codeErr=1");
   }
}
```

This validation is for my registration form, If all the fields are filled up it will check if the username that the user enters is already on the database or not, else, it will get an error message. If the username is already on the database, an error message will be outputted else it will proceed to the next page and all values will be inserted on the database. The problem is that whenever I enter the username which was already on the database, it still accepts the username. I can't find anything wrong with my validation code. Can someone help me out what could be the possible problem here? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: SQL injection deluxe I'd say. Do yourself a favor and switch from mysql_* functions to PDO and prepared statements. This normally also cleans up the code a little, you're mixing SQL code and the logic you have. I suggest you wrap some parts into functions of it's own.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for username and die after the redirect:

```
$tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user'])."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tbl);
if ($_POST['user'] == $row['username']){
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");
    die;
}
```

You code is SQL injection vulnerable:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

$tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user'])."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tbl);
if ($_POST['user'] == $row['username']){
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");
    die;
}

$name= $_POST['name'];
$lname= $_POST['lname'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if(($name!="") && ($lname!="") && ($add!="") && ($age!="") && ($contact!="") && ($email!="") && ($user!="") && ($pass!="")){
    $value=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(name, lastname, address, age, contact, email, username, password)
    VALUES 
    ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($lname)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($add)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($age)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($contact)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."')");
} else {
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr=1");
    die;
}
```

As a side note you should move to PDO or MySQLi as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.
[Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice tutorial and here is an example:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nnx;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION))

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `username` = :username");
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['user']));
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($row_count){
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");
    die;
}

if(($name!="") && ($lname!="") && ($add!="") && ($age!="") && ($contact!="") && ($email!="") && ($user!="") && ($pass!="")){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `tablename`(`name`, `lastname`, `address`, `age`, `contact`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (:name, :lname, :address, :age, :contact, :email, :username, :password)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'], ':lname' => $_POST['lname'], ':address' => $_POST['add'], ':age' => $_POST['age'], ':contact' => $_POST['contact'], ':email' => $_POST['email'], ':username' => $_POST['user'], ':password' => $_POST['pass']));
} else {
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr=1");
    die;
}
```

This way your are sql injection free.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$add=$_POST['add'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

if(($name!="")&&($lname!="")&&($add!="")&&($age!="")&&($contact!="")&& ($email!="")&&($user!="")&&($pass!=""))
{
    $tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename where username = '{$user}'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($tbl);
    if($num_rows > 0){
        header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");
    } else {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
        {
            $value=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(name, lastname, address, age, contact,email, username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['add']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['pass']."')");
        }
    }
} else {
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr=1");
}

?>
```